# MemoryStream cannot be expanded...refactoring from FileStream to MemoryStream or similar

Tags: c#, arrays, stream

I have a problem refactoring a chunk of code. I vaguely understand the problem but a little more insight and or explanation would be very helpful to my understanding and resolving the problem.

First the original chunk of code:

```
FileStream fS = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
Int64 fSLength = fS.Length;
Int64 remainingNotFulEncDecBlock = fSLength % 1;
fS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
Int64 nrBytesToAdd = 1 - remainingNotFulEncDecBlock;

Byte fillByte = (Byte)'$';

  for (Int32 i = 0; i < nrBytesToAdd - 1; i++)
    fS.WriteByte(fillByte);
    fS.WriteByte((Byte)nrBytesToAdd);
    fSLength = fS.Length;
    fS.Close();
```

The only purpose to the refactor is that we no longer have a physical file to open. Instead we provide a `byte[]`.

Here is my refactored code:

```
MemoryStream fS = new MemoryStream(_data);
Int64 fSLength = fS.Length;
Int64 remainingNotFulEncDecBlock = fSLength % 1;
fS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
Int64 nrBytesToAdd = 1 - remainingNotFulEncDecBlock;

Byte fillByte = (Byte)'$';
  for (Int32 i = 0; i < nrBytesToAdd - 1; i++)
    fS.WriteByte(fillByte);
    fS.WriteByte((Byte)nrBytesToAdd);
    fSLength = fS.Length;
    fS.Close();
```

The code above produces the error `MemoryStream` cannot be expanded on the line

```
fS.WriteByte((Byte)nrBytesToAdd);
```

Originally I had to Google the error and read up. This now makes sense as the memory stream has been set to a specific size. What I am unclear on is how should I proceed. Do I create another `MemoryStream` object that is NOT set to a specific size thus allowing me to do something like:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ms.WriteByte((Byte)nrBytesToAdd);
```

My reading of this technique indicates this will be less performant than initializing a `MemoryStream` to a specified `byte[]` however I don't know of (can't find) another way to expand `MemoryStream` dynamically. One plus is that now and in the foreseen future the `byte[]` coming in will be very small so while slower probably won't make a drastic impact on performance.

Comment: A `MemoryStream` can be resized as long as you don't initialize it with a specific `byte[]` buffer (i.e. use it in any way other than how you're using it here). But the code you posted makes so little sense, it's hard to know what the right answer would be. `fsLength % 1` always returns 0, so why bother? And given that, how does your loop ever do anything, since `nrBytesToAdd` is always 1 and so `i < nrBytesToAdd - 1` is always false. If you want a truly useful answer to your question you should post a good code example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the MemeoryStream [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx3c0489%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes an initial capacity.

```
MemoryStream fS = new MemoryStream(_data.Length);
```

This will set up the internal byte array of that size so the memory stream doesn't have to keep expanding the array each time it hits it's size limit.  It will allow you to add bytes to the memory stream.  While not as effective as just having a static byte[] size it's probably the next best thing.

Comment: Just to clarify,the initial capacity [MemoryStream(int)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_MemoryStream__ctor_System_Int32_) overload still allows expansion